# bring uwp app in foreground

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app

I found [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755360/uwp-detect-app-gaining-losing-focus) about how to detect if the app runs in foreground. Is it possible to bring my UWP app to the foreground (when it runs in the background) somehow? Maybe it's possible with a background task?

Comment: It is the user who is supposed to bring the app to foreground. You can send user a notification (for example toast) form the background, but AFAIK user interaction is a must.

Comment: I'm trying to convert my desktop app (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/coffee-clock/9nblggh442p4) to a pure uwp app. Bring the uwp app to the foreground would be necessary.

Comment: You would typically use notifications for this.

Comment: Too bad. With notifications I can't show my awesome custom reminder screen.

Comment: @Briefkasten You could use [Adaptive and interactive toast notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-adaptive-interactive-toasts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I got it to work for UWP running on Windows 10:

1. In your manifest create a protocol declaration (insert Name and Display name meaningful to your app)

   As explained here: https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/make-an-app-respond-to-url-requests-using-protocol-declaration/

> Start creating a new Windows Store app. For our purpose, a Blank App
> is enough. Now, we need to open the Package.appxmanifest file, go to
> Declarations tab and add Protocol from the Available Declarations
> list. Then, we specify the URI schema we want to handle in the Name
> property:

2. In App settings for the protocol change the Desired view to *Use Half*
3. Use the Launcher to call your registered protocol whenever your app should come to the foreground

In the example below replace `yourprotocolhere` with the protocol you registered for your app.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("yourprotocolhere://"));
```

Comment: The behavior of LaunchUriAsync is not always the same. Sometimes it will bring the app to the foreground, but sometimes it will just stay in the toolbar and blink. But so far this is also the only way I can find..